# How can I select all the text I typed in vsc integrated terminal

Tags: visual-studio-code

How can I select all the text I typed in vsc integrated terminal? This https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/terminal/basics#_select-all selects the entire terminal text instead of just text that I typed

i.e.

[image]

Comment: You can't select **only** the commands you typed. What you can do is press `F8` in the terminal (if using command prompt / windows terminal) and copy the command history shown there, or the `history` command on bash.

Comment: @EthanR Oh that seems to be a pain. I'm just trying to ctrl + a my text like in the regular terminal, you're sure this feature isn't available in vsc terminal?

Comment: @meghidey ctrl+shift+left arrow could be a bit more precise

Comment: @Costa That seems to work in the normal terminal, but in the vsc terminal it instead goes to the first character I typed. Do you happen to know the keyboard shortcut command name for it?

Comment: @meghidey Yeah, if you go to keyboard shortcuts, its the "cursorWordLeftSelect"

Comment: @Costa Ah yeah that shortcut work does the left word select properly for regular files but I cant seem to get it working for the vsc terminal :/ any ideas?

Comment: @meghidey Don't have any other ideas but it works on powershell (in vscode) for sure :D

Comment: @Costa Ah you're right it does, might consider moving over for better shortcut support, thanks for the help!